# How can I define a optional part in the pattern?

Tags: php, regex

Here is [my content](https://regex101.com/r/D6Qas8/3):

```
<div>something</div>
<div>something else <p>paragraph</p></div>
```

And this is my pattern:

```
/<div>([^<]+).*?<\/div>/
```

As you see, it matches just the text content of `div`. Now I want to add an optional part to the pattern for `p`. I mean, I want to get `p`'s value as another capturing group if it exists.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. Try with an HTML parser instead.

Comment: @Mistalis Actually it's a simplified of my real content. My real content isn't HTML markup. So I don't want to parse the HTML via RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<div>([^<]+)(<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?<\/div>` :

## regex demo

for your input :

```
<div>something</div>
<div>something else <p>paragraph</p></div>
```

**Output**

```
something
something else 
paragraph
```

Comment: Good. thank you, upvote. Also I don't need to capture `<p>` tag. https://regex101.com/r/8Vnxzh/4

Comment: you are welcome @MartinAJ